# Android WebView translation missing in date and time picker for HTML input type date and time

Tags: android, android-webview, translation, html-input

When I use HTML input type time or date in an Android WebView, then the translation for set and clear is missing in the date and time picker.

In this example I'm using Dutch as language.
Sample website used in WebView and Chrome browser app: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

In Android WebView the translation for set and clear is missing.

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.loadUrl("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time")
```

[image]

In the Chrome browser app the Dutch translation is correct.
[image]

Is there a way to overwrite these translations or how can I fix this?